# Periods in Angular query parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing

I'm building a route in angular.js like so:

```
$routeProvider
  .when('/ui/:id/foo/:netloc', {
    controller:'FooController',
    templateUrl:'/views/foo.html'
  })
```

The trouble is really simple - I want netloc to be able to be a dns or ip address. So sample routable paths might look like...

```
/ui/12345/foo/here.or.there.com/
/ui/54321/foo/10.24.36.48/
```

Unfortunately, while I found that it successfully routes this:

```
/ui/12345/food/here/
```

It will not route any path where the parameter contains a period. I though perhaps it was trying to do some sort of format discovery magic, so I tried this:

```
/ui/12345/foo/here.com.html
```

But that didn't work either. Any ideas on how to make this work?

Comment: Try putting it up on http://plnkr.co It'll help to play around with the code.

Comment: Hmm... it works the plnkr. Must be a bug in my implementation. Sorry, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to most likely be a bug in your implementation. I tried it out locally and it worked fine.

Comment: I am embarrassed to say I believe you are correct. Sorry for the dumb question!

Comment: Its alright sometimes you need to run something by other people.